# Where is Windows 8 Metro Style List Picker

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

We have a listpicker control in Windows Phone 7 - That comes in fro0m windows Phone 7 toolkit.

Do we have a similar control for Windows 8 Metro Style Application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably implement it using a [listview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listview.aspx).  Just handle the [ItemClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.itemclick.aspx) event and change a property in the "view-model" for each item.  Bind the view of each item to the "selected" property of your view-model.

Answer (score 0):

Combo box is the control equivalent to ListPicker in Windows 8.. The xaml would be something like this..

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbFrequency">
    <ComboBoxItem Text="Daily"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Text="Monthly"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Text="Weekly"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Text="Yearly"/>
</ComboBox>
```

The same can be done dynamically in the code behind like this

```
var frequencyList = new List<string> {"Daily", "Monthly", "Weekly", "Yearly"};
cbFrequency.ItemsSource = frequencyList;
```